# How to limit number of elements in Flux<Map<K,V>> and map this to the custom result

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, spring-webflux, java-11

Let's say that I have classes that illustrate the problem of songs and votes voted for.

User.java

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

  @Id private String id;

  private String username;

  private String email;

  private Integer age;

  private String password;

  @DBRef(db = "interview", lazy = true)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Set<Song> songs;
}
```

Song.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Song {

  @Id private String id;

  private String title;

  private String author;

  private SongGenre songGenre;

  Set<Vote> votesOfSong;
}
```

Vote.java

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "votes")
@Getter
public class Vote {

  @Id private String id;

  private User user;

  private Song song;

  private VoteKind voteKind;

  @Default private LocalDateTime dateOfVote = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

and

VoteKind.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum VoteKind {
  LIKE(1),
  DISLIKE(-1);

  private final Integer voteValue;
}
```

I want to create a method which will return the most common `SongGenre`, `SongTitle` and number of votes for a particular song.

So far I have a methods like:

```
public Flux<Map<Song, SongGenre>> theMostCommonSongForSongGenre(SongGenre songGenre) {
    voteRepository
        .findAll()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(vote -> vote.getSong().getSongGenre(), this::getSumOfVotesForVote))
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
        .filter(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getKey().equals(songGenre))
        .sort(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getKey(), o -> o.getValue()));
  }
```

and the helper method:

```
  private int getSumOfVotesForSong(Vote vote) {
    return vote.getSong().getVotesOfSong().stream()
        .mapToInt(voteKind -> vote.getVoteKind().getVoteValue())
        .sum();
  }
```

There are two problems here that I cannot quite solve.

1. How to limit the result of my Flux to for instance 1 or 10 records. In a conventional way, in Java Stream API, I can use methods `findFirst` or `limit` but here there is no another equivalent method. The only method I can call is `limitRate` but it has another predestination.
2. How to convert current solution to return `SongGenre`, `SongTitle` and number of votes for a particular song. Is there any chance to return MultiMap for above parameters or I should use `groupingBy` and return a custom object with `songGenre` and `songTitle` as key and as value Integer which will be equivalent to number of votes.

EDIT:
Core java stream solution can be either desirable.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `Flux` is to make it so calling client doesn't have to wait until `findAll()` completes?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks for your comment. It's according to point 1, right?

Comment: No, just in general. With code you're showing all questions are solved exactly the same way as in Java 8, because it effectively **is** the Java 8 code, but it calls `Flux.just(myMap)` at the very end, effectively (but in a lot more confusing way, so it might not be obvious).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov ok, understand. So know my mechanism is doing typical Java 8 job and after all, it's not reactive approach, right?

Comment: Looking at it again, if your `findAll` returns a `Flux`, then it is "reactive", and I am mistaken. Though it's built in such way that there is no benefit to limiting the number of items in output, because this code absolutely has to load everything into memory, twice: first to collect into a map, and then second time for sorting. Operation you seem to ask about is called `limitRequest(size)` in reactor, but you should rethink how you do things. Current solution will not scale - your app will run out of memory if there are a lot of songs. Push those filters further down, to datasource level.

Comment: your `voteRepository` what does it return, a concrete type or `Mono` or a `Flux`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf it's returning Flux<Vote> for findAll method.

Comment: i agree with the above, you are basically telling the database "give me everything" and then you wait for everything, and collect it, sure it may be reactive as it waits the threads can do something else, but still. What you basically want to return is a Mono<List<Map<K, V>>> not a Flux. A flux is a constant stream of values, not a finite list. Thats what a mono is for.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thank you so much for a response. Would you mind to write down a solution, which in your opinion will be proper according to the fact that WebFlux won't deal with nested reactive types?

Comment: since you are looking for a finite number of items (you want specifically 10 items) you should look into writing a proper database query that returns what it is you are looking for instead of fetching everything and then doing all the filtering server side. And then instead of returning a flux, return a `Mono<T>` to the client

Answer (score 6):

If you're using reactive you generally want to avoid things like collect() as it's blocking.  You can call collectList() on the flux to get a mono of that list.

Flux has a take() method to limit the results.